# how to adapt old openlayers code with call to TMS to openlayers6

Tags: openlayers-3, openlayers-6

How to adapt this old code to openlayers 6

```
var layer_ais = new OpenLayers.Layer.TMS(
    "Traffic maritime",
    "https://tiles.marinetraffic.com/ais_helpers/shiptilesingle.aspx?output=png&sat=1&grouping=shiptype&tile_size=512&legends=1&zoom=${z}&X=${x}&Y=${y}",
    {
    "layerId":2,
    "displayOutsideMaxExtent":true,
    "isBaseLayer":false,
    "numZoomLevels":18,
    "type":"png",
    "url":"https:\/\/tiles.marinetraffic.com\/ais_helpers\/shiptilesingle.aspx?output=png&sat=1&grouping=shiptype&tile_size=512&legends=1&zoom=${z}&X=${x}&Y=${y}" ,
    'getURL': getTileURLMarine,
    'tileSize': new OpenLayers.Size(512,512)
    });
```

must i use a XYZ or WMS source ?
must i use a tileUrlFunction to reorder the z x y parameter as in this example ?
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/xyz-esri-4326-512.html

according with @Mike help here is the working code for ol 6.2

```
      var defaultGrid = new ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({ tileSize: 256,  maxZoom: 18 });
      var layer_ais = new ol.layer.Tile({
         source: new ol.source.XYZ({
            tileGrid: new  ol.tilegrid.TileGrid({
               tileSize: 512,
               resolutions: defaultGrid.getResolutions(),
               extent: defaultGrid.getExtent()
            }),
         url: "https://tiles.marinetraffic.com/ais_helpers/shiptilesingle.aspx?output=png&sat=1&grouping=shiptype&tile_size=512&legends=1&zoom={z}&X={x}&Y={y}"
        })
      });
```

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an XYZ url so you cannot WMS.  If you have a standard tile grid you can use a {-y} placeholder ($ is no longer used in placeholders):

```
var layer_ais = new ol.layer.TileLayer({
  source: new ol.source.XYZ({
     maxZoom: 18,
     tileSize: 512,
     url: 'https://tiles.marinetraffic.com/ais_helpers/shiptilesingle.aspx?output=png&sat=1&grouping=shiptype&tile_size=512&legends=1&zoom={z}&X={x}&Y={-y}'
  })
});
```

Comment: many thanks mike for the help it works but i still have a projection prob ?...[https://codesandbox.io/s/reprojection-wgs84-l5umh](https://codesandbox.io/s/reprojection-wgs84-l5umh)

Comment: the old code used : projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913") <== who is the same of ol .... and displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),

Comment: "900913" is "GOOGLE" (the same as EPSG:3857 which is OpenLayers and OSM default).  I got your sandbox working, it is a normal XYZ layer (not TMS) except the first level uses the same resolution with 512px tiles as with 256px.  With the latest dev version you can use the maxResolution option to customise the tile grid https://codesandbox.io/s/reprojection-wgs84-fxe30

Comment: thanks Mike works perfect on codesansbox with the latest dev version ! ... How /where i can get this version js and css file ....i am not familiar with npm ....  to try on my web site ?

Comment: You can use the old longer method of creating a tilegrid with resolutions for 256px tiles but set to use 512px https://codesandbox.io/s/reprojection-wgs84-l3s3k